# Moving Android studio to a new PC

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

I have a class with 30 Windows 10 computers running Android Studio.

Because it's a classroom, the computers have restrictions on installing software and everything is deleted after a reboot.

When we installed Android Studio 2.3.3 (2 years ago), we installed a lot of SDK tools and add-ons...(like Firebase)

Now we are formatting all the computers again and we want to update them all to Android Studio 3.3.

When we updated Android Studio in the old OS the students projects and the emulators worked great on Android studio 3.3, but on the new Windows installation where we have installed Android Studio nothing works properly (Gradle, emulator, Firebase and more...)

My question is:

Is there a way to copy the full Android Studio software with all of the add-ons and settings from one PC to another?

Can I copy the folder from the `C` drive?

I tried to use `import settings` in Android Studio and it didn't work.

Comment: Motherboard with the same chipset, and making an image.  There might also be some ways of making an image for computers with dissimlar chipsets. Another possibility is a VM. And another possibility is if there is a portable android studio

Answer (score 0):

Copying program folders to a new computer normally **won't work** (unless the program is portable).

The reason for this is that programs actually scatter their data all over the place. In addition to the program files, there are also:

- **Registry settings** - Many programs save settings in the Windows registry. These settings may be scattered all over the Windows registry — for example, there may be several registry keys for program settings, other registry keys for context menu options, and keys that make the program the default program for certain files. If any of these registry keys aren’t present, the program may display errors when you try to run it.
- **System Services** - Many programs install Windows services that they require. For example, Adobe Flash Player installs an Adobe Flash Player Update service. While you could copy the Adobe Flash plugin files to a new system, you wouldn’t have the update service and you’d have to manually update Adobe Flash. Installing Adobe Flash with the installer would ensure that the updater service is present. Some programs may not even run without these services available.
- **User Data Folders** - Most modern programs don’t save their settings to their program folder. Whatever they don’t store in the registry is likely stored in each user’s Application Data folder. Even if you could copy the program’s files over, these settings would have to be copied or you’d lose your programs’ settings and data.
- **Windows System Files** - Some programs dump DLL files and other files into the Windows system directory and won’t run if these files aren’t present.

Theoretically, it would be possible to locate everything — registry settings, program files, system files, user data folders — and copy them to the new computer, reinstalling any system services and putting everything in the exact same place. However, this would be extremely tedious and would often require using some sort of program that monitors the changes an installer makes.

In practice, simply reinstalling the program is much faster and easier. The installer will set up everything the program needs on your system. Once the installation for Android Studio has completed, then you can install any required add-ons.

Comment: I tried to install again the problem is that the projects of the students does not work on the new installation on android studio...
and I don't know what add ons are installed because someone else installed them...
maybe there is a way to view all the add ons installed?

Comment: What do you mean by _does not work_? Does Android Studio fail to start, do you receive an error message? etc

Comment: As general advice this is accurate. However for many programs it is infact possible to move user settings and data if it's known what should be moved.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator the OP mentioned only copying the folder from the C drive; although I have mentioned that, like you say, it is possible to locate all the necessary data and move it across.